# How can I install SSH server version 5.3

Tags: software-installation, openssh

I need to pentest the vulnerability of the "SSH Server v5.3"
The problem is that Ubuntu comes with the SSH Server version 7 and I don’t know how to remove the current one.

Probably: `apt remove ssh-server —purge`

But how can I apt install ssh-server 5.3?

Is there anyway searching in old apt repo for 5.3 version?

Thanks!

Comment: Download the tar ball from https://www.openssh.com/portable.html, then refer to the linked question.

Comment: I don't think questions about installing specific software that has to be compiled from source should be closed against that question, since it's often quite nontrivial to adapt the generic procedure (@DavidFoerster). I think these questions are answerable and should be answered

Comment: @Zanna: Agreed, but let's assume that it is trivial until OP finds out that it's not, at which point they hopefully [edit] their question and we can reopen (and answer) it.

Comment: Even your recommendation with an explanation of why portable OpenSSH is suitable for this purpose would be a good answer @DavidFoerster imho

Answer (score 1):

You can build and install a “portable” version of OpenSSH from source:

1. Download the tar ball for the desired version from one of the mirrors sites listed on https://openssh.com/portable.html.
2. OpenSSH installation follows the common procedure lined out in “[How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](/q/25961/175814)”:

   ```sh
   tar -xf [TARBALL]
   cd [EXTRACTED-PATH]
   ./configure [options...]
   make
   make install  # Use 'sudo' if you want to install for all users.
   ```

   ***In this particular case you may want to set an installation prefix to avoid the replacement or shadowing of the regular OpenSSH installation:***

   ```sh
   ./configure --prefix=[PREFIX]
   ```

   Suitable `PREFIX` paths might be somthing like `~/openssh-5.3` or `/opt/openssh-5.3`.
3. If you run into issue refer to the included installation instructions, typically in a files called `INSTALL` or `BUILDING`. You can also find it at http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/INSTALL.

   - The most likely issue are missing library dependencies.
4. If you can't solve the issue using the resources mentioned above you're welcome to edit your question and leave a comment below this answer to draw my attention to your changes.